# Domain name législation - legal - similar to other company

Tags: dns

Where can i find information about domain name law?
If for exemple i want to create a website named newwork.ch and a compny already have a domain named thenewwork.com can I use newwork.ch or am i running to problems?
How much can it be bad?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question as being about the policies.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an attorney but I'd recommend starting your research at Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers (ICANN) with particular attention paid to the [domain name dispute policy](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/dndr-2012-02-25-en) and related topics.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answear but I did not found on this website if my domain name is legal. is there no way / no form to find if a domain name is legal? Like a patent registry or clear rules algorithm to know if a domain name is in conflict with others?